# optimizacion de datos json para una mejor extraccion

Tags: json, angularjs-2.0, firebase, ionic2, estructuras-de-datos

Necesito orientación en cuanto a como estructurar unos datos para una mejor extracción e ultilización de estos.

Los datos que tengo tienen una estructura similara esto:

```
Clima->
region->provincia->ciudad->Farmnacias->
Bencinas->
informacion_adicional->
varios_datos_mas
```

y yo lo que hice fue crear cada nodo por separado identificando a cada nodo con un `ID` de la region, provincia y ciudad quedando algo asi:

```
 region
 provincia->idregion
 ciudad->idregion, idprovincia
 Clima->idciudad, idregion,idprovincia
 Farmnacias->idciudad, idregion,idprovincia
 Bencinas->idciudad, idregion,idprovincia
```

todos estos son insertados desde `php` hacia `firebase` database y luego hacia una app en `angualrJs2` y `ionic2`, agradecería cualquier tipo de ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

El `json` que esta debajo te puede servir de guía, seguramente no sea lo más óptimo porque no tengo toda la información sobre tu proyecto, pero es un buen punto de partida.

```
{
  "regiones": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "nombre": "Región 1",
      "provincias": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "nombre": "Provincia 1",
          "ciudades": [
            {
              "id": 1,
              "nombre": "Ciudad 1",
              "clima": "20°",
              "farmacias": [],
              "bencinas": []
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "nombre": "Provincia 2",
          "ciudades": []
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "nombre": "Región 2",
      "provincias": []
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: y si por ejemplo, en clima tengo que agregar datos de todos los dias con informacion. Como haria eso??

Comment: Si es poca información podrías crear un arreglo con la información directamente, y acceder a cada elemento por su índice, de esta manera: `["10°", "15°", "12°"]` En cambio, si es mucha información podrías crear un arreglo de objetos, y acceder a cada elemento por su clave, así: `{"Lunes" : ["10°", "12°], "Martes" : ["15°", "17°], "Miercoles" : ["12°", "14°"]}`